# PHP: Need to extract certain part of string using preg_match()

Tags: php

I'm try to extract the "INV" part of the string below:

```
123_456_P1234_INV_UID-123456.PDF
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
php -r 'echo preg_match("/_(.*?)_UID-.*?\.PDF$/", "123_456_P1234_INV_UID-123456.PDF", $cat) ? $cat[1]."\n" : "";'
```

This returns:

```
_456_P1234_INV
```

Can anyone tell me why it's including everything before the INV bit? How can I fetch just the INV part please?

Comment: Yes, though it may not always be "INV", which is why I'm using this method. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `.*` swallows everything, including _. Try this:

```
php -r 'echo preg_match("/([^_]*?)_UID-.*?\.PDF$/", "123_456_P1234_INV_UID-123456.PDF", $cat) ? $cat[1]."\n" : "";'
```

Update, after reading the answer to the comment on another answer:

```
php -r 'echo preg_match("/([^_]*_UID-.*)\.PDF$/", "123_456_P1234_INV_UID-123456.PDF", $cat) ? $cat[1]."\n" : "";'
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: The position of the ending parenthesis. It depends on if you want to have everything after INV or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change .*? by [^_]*

```
php -r 'echo preg_match("/_([^_]*)_UID-.*?\.PDF$/", "123_456_P1234_INV_UID-123456.PDF", $cat) ? $cat[1]."\n" : "";'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the () use you just want whatever is in *INV* correct?
If you're sure there is always a UID after this should work, NOTE: that INV can NEVER contain _.

```
php -r 'echo preg_match("/_(.[^_]*?)_UID-.*?\.PDF$/", "123_456_P1234_INV_UID-123456.PDF", $cat) ? $cat[1]."\n" : "";'
```